# Prove or disprove that if $a\mid(sb + tc)$ for all $s,t$ elements of integers, then $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Prove or disprove that if $a\mid(sb + tc)$ for all $s,t$ elements of integers, then $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$

My question is "for all". I'm clearly misunderstanding something, because my intuition is to say, well this is obviously not true for every integer $s,t$ and I can provide a counter-example. However, what I just suggested to do should be done if it said "there exists $s,t$ that are elements of integers".

can someone walk me through it?

Comment: And I can prove this. I can just say that let s=0 and t=1, the na|c because a| 1*c. and if I make s=1 and t=0, then a|b. thus, if a|(sb + tc) for all s,t, elements of integers, then by definition a|b and a|c.

But I still don't get how this is FOR ALL s,t, and not just the exclusive 2 cases where s=0 and t=1, and vice versa.

Comment: if its true for all integers then its true for (s,t)=(0,1) and (s,t)=(1,0) which proves it

Comment: if its true for (s,t)=(0,1) and (s,t)=(1,0) then a|b and a|c thus any linear combination of 'b' and 'c' is also divisible by 'a'  ie becomes true for any pair of ( s,t)

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = 1, t= 0 \to a\mid b$, and let $s = 0, t=1 \to a\mid c$.

Alternatively, if for all $s,t$ that $a\mid (sb+tc) \to a\mid \text{gcd(b,c)} \to a\mid b,a\mid c$.

Comment: My only question is the "for all s,t" not how to write the proof out. Why are we only settling for s=1 and t=0 and vice versa rather than s=3 and t= 50123012309, wouldn't these have to be true as it says "for all s,t elements of integers"?

Comment: so if I say find me a basket "for all apples in this room", and then say find me a basket "for some apples in this room", I would assume that in the first statements, I would be able to put all the apples in the baskets, but in the second I wouldn't be able to.

so when they say "for all integers s and t" I am assuming (wrongfully) that s can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 to infinity, but it only holds true if it's 0 or 1. this is my confusion.

Comment: I'm still not getting any help whatsoever. if s can be 1,2,3,4,5,6 then why are we only testing it for 1 and 0, and not the other numbers??? wouldn't this only be proving it true for 1,0?

Comment: Note that since letting $s = 1, t = 0, sb+tc = b$

Comment: duly noted, just as s=0 and t=1 then sb+tc = c
this still ignores the infinite amount of values for s,t for this to be true for all of them (again this is my understanding, and I know it's wrong).

Comment: but it gives you $a|b$, and $a|c$.